# Looking for the opposite of "drill down"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms, phrasal-verbs

I am a programmer working on a chart component that allows to drill down on selection of a node. Drilling down will show the details of that node (like its children etc.). But I am struggling to find out a word to describe the opposite of drilling down. "Drill up" sounds wrong. Does anyone have a nifty little word that conveys the opposite of "drilling down"? Something to convey the action of moving from something more specific to something more general.

Comment: Not every other sentence must end in a question mark ? And there is never , never a whitespace before the question mark or a period ? Come on , you 've been on the site for so long , you should know better .

Comment: @REGDWIGHТ Thanks for pointing . I edited the question.

Comment: And you have undone all of Reg's good work.

Comment: @AndrewLeach oops blame it on the concurrency handling of the site..His edits were not visible to me

Comment: I can think of one phrase which involves a rotating tool followed by the word 'up', but it's probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Drill up* is indeed what is used in a large number of instances. [Here's an example.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-kcKpqzbBR0C&pg=PA290&dq=%22drill+up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EI4sUfyDMtON0wWZtYHQBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22drill%20up%22&f=false)

However you could use ***zoom out*** to get the larger picture of the data.

Comment: I'd use zoom out.

Answer (score 5):

Drill up or Roll up can be used as opposite of drill down.It makes use of a decreasing granularity showing things more globally

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can use ***reverse drill down*** (or, *reverse drilldown*).

I found this on a [University of Georgia memo](http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0802d&L=sas-l&P=37593):

> The opposite of drill down is **reverse drill down** where the initial view is
>   at the most granular available level, rather than a summarised view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like one of these?

"back out", "expand out", "zoom back", "pull back", "unspecify", "despecify", "focus out"

Comment: I'd add "step back" to this list or "take a few steps back".

Answer (score -2):

"Drill up" doesn't make sense. "Roll up" also has diverse, different meanings, and I have never heard it used to mean to encompass a more general perspective. "Elevator view" is a good antonym. Less colorful would be "overview." Neither of these is a verb, but no good verb comes to mind.

Comment: To leave comments on other answers, it's better to use the comment feature directly rather than including them in your answer.